# Redirect all subpages back to the front page

Tags: redirection, path-aliases

I am trying to redirect everything that is under example.com/pictures back to the front page (i.e. I am hiding picture nodes to be directly viewable).

Neither the [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/projects/pathauto) module nor the [Global Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module allows me to do this (or I am overlooking something). I cannot simply block users from viewing that particular node type.

Is it possible doing this with a module? Should I hack something up? Would an .htaccess rewrite help me?

I am interested in an answer for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume "pictures", is a content type. If that's not the case, this may not work. Please provide more details about your setup in that case.

1. Install the [Chaos tool suite (ctools)](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) module, and enable the Page Manager module
2. Enable the node template
3. Create a variant of type "HTTP response code".
4. Set the response code to 301.
5. Set the path to <front>
6. Go to "Selection rules" in the left menu
7. Add "Node:type == 'pictures'"
8. Save

Answer (score 3):

I belive you search for this module [redirect](http://drupal.org/project/redirect).

Or you could use this example of an .htaccess 301 redirect, make sure your apache servers [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is enable

```
# Redirect "dir/*" to "/"
RewriteRule ^dir/ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
#
# no-www please
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# 301 Permanent Redirects
Redirect 301 /dir http://example.com/
```

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot that I had redirect already enabled. But the problem is the same: it only allows for per url redirection, not recursive.