# Redirect incoming traffic to homepage

Tags: redirection

How can I set Drupal 7 so that all incoming traffic is redirected to the homepage? I need to ensure all visitors go to the homepage, even if they click a link on some other site that links to example.com/section/node-1

Comment: What do mean by all 'incoming' traffic. All visitors where the referrer is from another domain and not your website? Or first time visitors?

Comment: I mean all referrers from a domain that isn't my website, first time visitor's don't matter. I should clarify, I am looking to do this in the interface, not programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this easier in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule $ / [R=302,L]
```

Put this at the bottom of your .htaccess file and you're set.

Comment: I should clarify, I am looking to do this in the interface, not programmatically.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19065/redirect-all-subpages-back-to-the-front-page may help you out, but my htaccess solution is the way to go

Comment: Does this redirect all requests to the homepage or only incoming traffic (from another domain) ?

Comment: This redirects all urls on the website domain to the homepage, essentially all domain.com/* to domain.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
function yourmodule_init() {
  $destination = drupal_get_destination();
  if ($destination['destination'] != variable_get('site_frontpage', 'url-home')) {
    drupal_goto('<front>');
  }
}
```

And you Can add to th if statement your custom conditions

Hope this helps

Comment: I should clarify, I am looking to do this in the interface, not programmatically.

Comment: So probably you will be able to do this with rules. You can take a look.

Answer (score -1):

Here are rewrite conditions to redirect all incoming traffic (from another domain) to the homepage. Put this in the `.htaccess` file.

Don't forget to update the URL with your correct website domain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://([^.]+\.)*yourdomain\.com 
RewriteRule / http://www.yourdomain.com [R=301,L]
```