# Unpublished Nodes and Content Access

Tags: 7, users

I have a view that relies on a specific content type to display images. The Content Type has a Title,  a File Field, and a checkbox for show or don't show.  The default setting for all nodes created using this Content Type is unpublished, so that users can't randomly access the node ( basically it's a slideshow that displays banner ads, accessing the actual node isn't a bad problem per se ).

This works great.  As it turns out I also need a members only section for the site, so I installed Content Access.  That works great for restricting access to the nodes I need restricted.  However, I discovered that now the unpublished Slideshow nodes don't show.

My question is how to work around this.  Will another access module work differently or is this a core feature?  Could I write a small module to grant view access to the Slideshow nodes?  Or barring all that, is there a module or ( I know it's probably off-topic) an htaccess recipe that would not allow direct viewing of the nodes of a certain type?

Comment: It sounds as if you just need to check your configuration for Slideshow content type. If this is not what you meant, please elaborate more as it's not quite clear what are you trying to achieve and where is the problem exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by making the Content Type nodes published again.  So in my View I check to see if the checkbox is check AND if the node is Published.  The slider works as it should.  I was then left with the task of deciding if allowing access to the actual node was desirable.  Viewing the direct node in my case was not all that bad, it's not restricted content or anything but I felt it would just be sloppy.  So since I had Panels already installed, this solution https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/19072/12881 worked out great.  If someone stumbled upon one of the nodes of that specific Content Type they're just sent to the front page.